# Sending email from a non existing mail id (noreply@myserver.com) in Nodejs using nodemailer npm

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Below is the sample code am using for sending mail.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.office365.com', 
    port: 587, 
    auth: {
        user: 'me@myserver.com',
        pass: 'mypassword'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'no-reply@myserver.com', //It will work if i give me@myserver.com but i need no-reply@myserver.com in from option.        
    to: 'someuser@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
     console.log(error);
    } else {
     console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

I will give me below error if i use `no-reply@myserver.com` in from option.

> Error: Message failed: 554 5.2.0
>   STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied;
>   Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message
>   Cannot submit message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some email servers do not accept changing **FROM** address. This is not about `nodemailer`. You need to check your email server configuration.

Comment: But when you provide auth in createTransport as option, nodemailer don't need local email server configuration to send mail.

Comment: May be i should try without auth and setting up smtp in my system.

Comment: You were right smtp.office365.com was my email server which is not accept changing from address and also not allowing to send anonymous mail. I tried with our company smtp server without auth and it worked, But i needed to add tls.rejectUnauthorized in transport settings as my host was not having a valid certificate.